# Rxjs - Combine 2 Observables and emit combined results not working

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

First off, here are my import statements for rxjs:

```
import { Subject, Observable, merge, combineLatest } from "rxjs";
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Here is my rxjs version in package.json:
`"rxjs": "^6.5.2"`

I have an Observable (`this.searchResults$`) which emits the results of a search API request. I now want to do another search and combine the new search results with the old search results, and put them all in `this.searchResults$`. `this.handleSearch()` returns the observable with the search results

I thought I would do this:

```
const newSearchResults$ = this.handleSearch(undefined, this.currentPage + x);
merge(newSearchResults$, this.searchResults$).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

But this console logs:

```
(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

The second line of the console log needs to contain 16 items. Instead it gets overwritten with the new 6 items.

I looked online why merge does not combine the results and found that I should use `combineLatest`:

```
const newSearchResults$ = this.handleSearch(undefined, this.currentPage + x);
newSearchResults$.subscribe(x => x);
const combinedSearchResults$ = combineLatest(newSearchResults$, this.searchResults$)
    .pipe(map(([s1, s2]: Array < any > ) => [...s1, ...s2]));
combinedSearchResults$.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

This does not console.log anything at all and has no errors. What am I doing wrong?

As per Pavel's answer I tried:

```
const newSearchResults$ = this.handleSearch(undefined, this.currentPage + x);
this.searchResults$.pipe(
    mergeMap((d1: any) => newSearchResults$.pipe(map(d2 => [...d1, ...d2])))
).subscribe(console.log);
```

I can't get anything to console.log with this either.

Comment: can you reproduce the issue online stackblitz perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wan't to merge 2 observables you can use mergemap operator.
try something like this:

```
var obs1 = lastData;
var obs2 = newData;

obs1.pipe(
    mergeMap(d1 => obs2.pipe(map(d2 => [...d1, ...d2])))
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Secondly be aware if you use cold or hot observable, because if you use the cold one the value won't be saved and the API will be called each time you subscribe to it. (you can create hot observable from cold with shareReplay operator.

Or you can use BehaviorSubject like in this example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dkh5ji

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't seem to console log anything either. I've added my code to the bottom of the question

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins it shoud work. I tryed it here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-edekwg

Comment: actualy you can use BehaviorSubject, which stores last emited value and you can emit new one i added a example to the end of my answer